# Git Commit Geolocation

Tags: git, github, geolocation

Is it possible to track geodata of Git commits? I realize doing this natively would be a huge privacy no-no but has anyone implemented this feature on a private or company repository using git hooks or something else?

Comment: this may be possible with GitHub Enterprise. What are you trying to track/prevent?